# copy by value object with no __deepcopy__ attr

Tags: python, copy

I'm trying to deepcopy an instance of a class, but I get a:

```
object has no __deepcopy__ atrribute
```

error.

The class is locked away in a `.pyd`, so it cannot be modified.

Is there a way to copy these objects by value without using deepcopy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to copy the object state. The easiest way would be to use the `pickle` module:

```
import pickle

copy = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(someobject))
```

This is *not guaranteed to work*. All the pickle module does for you in the general case is to pickle the instance attributes, and restore the instance a-new from the class reference and restore the attribute contents on that.

Since this is a C extension object, if the instance state is not exposed to you, and pickling is not explicitly supported by the type, this won't work either. In that case, you have no other options, I'm afraid.

Comment: The instance state was not exposed to me, so I had to define a class of objects that copied out relevant attribute values from the original (uncopyable) objects.